# How to visualize a SIFT keypoints

Tags: matlab, visualization, computer-vision, sift

I have got a lot of SIFT keypionts(some 128-dimension vectors), given a SIFT keypoints, I want to get the visualization picture(as the [two tiny pics](http://www.flickr.com/photos/mylovelymelo/5728742999/in/set-72157626739613970/) on the right side, how can I do that? I need servral lines of MATLAB code to achieve this, dose anybody can do me a favor?
many thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing not a whole lot of people know about SIFT keypoints. Perhaps if you explain the problem in a more detailed manner, someone could advise you on steps to take.

Comment: I know about SIFT, but you might start out by explaining what those images on the right are.

Answer (score 2):

The images on the right look like they might be the difference-of-Gaussians image that led to the selection of the keypoints.

If you have access to the inner workings of your SIFT algorithm, you can just take them from there. When a stable maxima is detected, keep the Difference-of-Gaussian image that led to its detection.

If you don't have access to the DoG images, it will be a little more work. You'll have to compute the Difference of Gaussian image yourself given the keypoint information. If the scale of your keypoint is stored in `sigma` and you have vlfeat (www.vlfeat.org), you should be able to compute it (approximately) as follows:

```
i = imread(any one of your images)
g1 = vl_imsmooth(i, 0.9 * sigma);
g2 = vl_imsmooth(i, 1.1 * sigma);
DoG = g2 - g1;
```

and your little image will be a square region around the location of your keypoint of interest.

I'm not sure if this is actually what those images are, but it's my best guess.

Answer (score 1):

For visualization of corresponding SIFT points in two images you can do as done in [David Lowe's SIFT demo](http://people.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/keypoints/) in match.m
Check the portion after

> % Show a figure with lines joining the
>   accepted matches.

Hope this helps.